# Change PHP $PATH setting?

Tags: macos, terminal, path

How to change `PHP` `$PATH` setting?

I am using MAMP 2.x, my terminal for `PHP` command is already set to the MAMP PHP `5.3.x`, but now I want to change to PHP `5.2.x`

I have done this before, but i forget the location of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it located at `/etc/paths` we can edit it from terminal with this code

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```